# DBpedia resource amount

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Iam new to DBpedia and SPARQL,I know same basics, but Iam really confused... I would like to get number of all DBpedia resources (`http://www.dbpedia.org/resource/xxxxxx`) but I dont really know what SPARQL query should be used.

Simply - I do not know how to ask for number of resources.

Is the number of those resources equal to number of all "subject" from this query?

```
SELECT (count(distinct ?sub ) as ?amount) WHERE { ?sub ?predic ?obj . }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, in theory your query is correct but as you might have seen DBpedia is very huge and query results with timeout. If you want you can see some statistics of DBpedia from this page (http://wiki.dbpedia.org/develop/datasets/dbpedia-version-2016-10).

Comment: No, you query returns exactly what is does: The number of RDF resources in subject position of a triple.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick reply. But I am not sure if I fully understand.  @AKSW - is this number useable for something? 
How do I get number of resources?

Comment: I just said that formally, this only returns subjects. think of resources, that don't have outgoing triples, i.e. that never occur in subject position but only object position. `SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?x) AS ?cnt) WHERE { {?x ?p ?o} UNION {?s ?p ?x} }` . Some datasets also provide statistics, but most don't.

Comment: I think I found solution. Please tell me Iam right.

SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?resource ) AS ?resources_amount)
WHERE {
?resource rdf:type owl:Thing .
}

I think every resource page is subclass of owl:Thing as ontology schema http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/ shows. Right?

Comment: This might work for DBpedia, but doesn't hold for RDF datasets in general. Still, I don't know why you can't take the published stats form the DBpedia page. They already provide all those numbers whenever they publish a new release.

Comment: Yes, but when I want to search smaller dbpedia for some countries, those stats wont help me.

Comment: HTH: `https://dbpedia.org/sparql?qtxt=select+*+from+named+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fvoid%2F%3E+{graph+%3Fg+{%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo}}+&format=text%2Fhtml`

Comment: Also, e. g. `http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatAmbassadorsOfBangladeshToVenezuela` is not a `owl:Thing`. It doesn't have `rdf:type` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answers the original question, by getting [the count of all entities with "/resource/" in their URI](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%28%20COUNT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%29%20AS%20%3FNumberOfResources%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20REGEX%20%28STR%20%28%3Fs%29%2C%20%22resource%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) (currently `5,489,631`) --

```
SELECT ( COUNT ( DISTINCT ?s ) AS ?NumberOfResources )
WHERE
  {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER ( REGEX ( STR ( ?s ), "/resource/" ) )
  }
```

That said, the comments suggest that this is not really what was desired.  Rewriting the question would likely help get a better answer.  Be careful not to fall victim to [the X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)!